# Mendeley desktop "Authenticate Account"

Tags: mendeley

When I log into my Mendeley desktop, a blue notice appears saying "We are changing the way we authenticate Mendeley accounts. Please enter your password to authenticate your account."; with a button to "Authenticate Account". When I click on the "Authenticate Account", it freezes the app; I saved my user/pass before so I don't think it would be the issue. 
Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the application again and it worked properly.